# Как расположить блоки сайта для планшета и мобилки?

Tags: html, css

учусь верстать сайты. Нашел макет сайта в интернете. Сверстал ПК версию сайта.
Хочу сделать добавить адаптивность для планшетов и мобилки.
Пожалуйста подскажите, как правильно расположить блоки сайта для планшетов и мобилки.
Ширина сайта 1300px, ширина контента 1140px.
Картинка сайта по ссылке.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvyIk.jpg

Comment: как тебе нравится, так и располагай

Comment: Однозначного ответа нет и быть не может. Лучше почитать соответствующие статьи вида "верстка мобильных версий сайтов", коих в интернете сейчас очень много. Выбирать те, что посвежее, естественно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не парился и сделал все гамбургером одно под другим, это же классический подход :) (Гамбургер меню не зря же придумали). При этом скрыл бы от глаза в мобильной версии не особо важный контент, что бы не засорять мобильную версию. А у версии для ПК включил бы видимость обратно.